# MANPATH in man.conf

Tags: path, mac-osx, man

I've installed mac-ports which puts everything under `/opt/local`. The corresponding man pages are in `/opt/local/man`. I added the following line to `/private/etc/man.conf` representing the `man` search path for `port`:

```
MANPATH /opt/local/man/man1
```

However, when I invoke `man` on its own:

```
> man port
```

I get the following error:

```
No manual entry for port
```

Is this the correct way to add a new search path for `man`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. You should have added this:

```
MANPATH /opt/local/man/
```

Not with /man1 appended to it. In /private/etc/man.conf, there's a line commented that you simply have to uncomment:

```
# Uncomment if you want to include one of these by default
#
# MANPATH       /opt/*/man
# MANPATH       /usr/lib/*/man
```

The /opt/*/man is your...man.

Comment: And because MANPATH is an environment variable, you need to restart your environment (e.g. new shell, etc) so that man.conf is re-parsed and MANPATH set to include the new directory.

Comment: Technically it's /opt/local/share/man -- beware if it suddenly stops working in the future :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to point to the root, so:

```
MANPATH=/opt/local/man man port
```

should work.

You should add any additional paths you have to /etc/manpath.config so that they'll work for everyone.

Comment: +1 for the tip to add to /etc/manpath.config